# display dynamic tags with time delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a set of div tags inside a main div tag which i display in an order based on a condition. I will have to display the inner div tags after a time delay as line by line. How do i do that?

```
<div id="comments" class = "u4073_container">
@if (@Messages != null)
{
for (int i = 0; i < Messages.Count; i++)
{
    if (Messages[i].MessageType == 0)
    {
            <div id="lblBlack" style="color:black;font-size: 13px;font-style: normal; font-family: Arial;">@Messages[i].Message </div>
            <div style="height: 5px;"></div>                

    }
    else if (Messages[i].MessageType == 1)
    {
            <div id="lblGreen" style="color:green;font-size: 13px;font-style: normal; font-family: Arial;">@Messages[i].Message </div>
            <div style="height: 5px;"></div>
    }
    else if (Messages[i].MessageType == 2)
    {
            <div id="lblRed" style="color:red;font-size: 13px;font-style: normal; font-family: Arial;">@Messages[i].Message </div>
            <div style="height: 5px;"></div>
    }
    else if (Messages[i].MessageType == 3)
    {
            <div id="lblBlue" style="color:blue;font-size: 13px;font-style: normal; font-family: Arial;">@Messages[i].Message </div>
            <div style="height: 5px;"></div>
    }

}
}
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for the help !!!

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, the `id` attribute must be unique per page. If you have two of the same `MessageType` in your collection, you'll have an invalid HTML page. Also, you've duplicated a bunch of code for no good reason.. Wouldn't it be much simpler to put the `id` in a variable depending on your conditions and then print the div once with that variable instead of copy pasting it 4 times?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is do the processing on the client side when all content was already generated, right? First, you should set the following style:

```
#comments > div { display: none; }
```

then, your Script might look similar to this:

```
$(function() {
    var to = 0;
    $("#comments > div").each(function(i, e) {
        to += 500;
        setTimeout(function() { $(e).fadeIn(); }, to);
    });
});
```

this should work, but your "spacer" divs would count there as well. Get rid of them, just add `margin-bottom: 5px` to your `lbl*` divs.

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wWgbK/). Of course, you can control the timeout by adjusting the `500` (ms) number.